# Regex to select last line in a multi-line string

Tags: regex, ant, hex

I have an ANT script which will have a property whose value could be one or more lines e.g.
property

```
prop1=
A_12.1_REL_B121000_10_18_2011.1700
A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.6059
A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2201
A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2014
```

Please see that all these lines end with a CRLF and end of file is also another CRLF. Now what I need to do is just select the last line using a regex. The number of lines could be less or more e.g

```
prop1=
    A_12.1_REL_B121000_10_18_2011.1700
```

In the second case I need to select this single line .
I have searched older posts, but could not find anything specific. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) :

```
    <loadfile srcFile="input.prop" property="test"/>

    <propertyregex property="result"
                   input="${test}"
                   regexp="(.*$)"
                   select="\1"
    />

    <echo message="Result is : ${result}"/>
```

This will always print the last line of your input properties file :

```
[echo] Result is : A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2014
```

Comment: SUPER.. this worked even while I am generating the property at run time from a `exec cleartool` command. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

This should do it...

```
/^.*\z/m
```

[See it in action](http://regexr.com?2v7v8).

(assume the `m` is multi-line mode.)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I saw ur answer in action but just need to check it in my script to accept it as THE answer.Also, I am not able to find out whats wrong with this one '\b(\w|\.)+(\s)$'.

Comment: this one doesn't work in ANT. Though the one which FailedDev has provided works for me. Thanks for the knowledge on \z/m though.