# How to rebase in ClearCase on latest baselines?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

From the `cleartool rebase` command I am able to rebase my stream on recommended baselines with the command:

```
cleartool rebase -rec -view ViewTag -stream stream:Stream@/PVOB
```

All the components in the stream are rebased to recommended baselines after running that command.

Is there any option for the `cleartool rebase` command to rebase on the latest baselines instead of recommended baselines? I tried cleartool rebase help, but I didn't find any option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the option

```
-bas/eline baseline-selector[,...]
```

And list the latest baselines yourself (as opposed to the `-recommended` option, which will take automatically the recommended baselines from the parent stream)

See "[Rules for rebasing a stream](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm#ref_rebase_refsect2_12842125)" to select the latest baselines: said baselines must have been produced in the parent stream of the one you are rebasing.

See "[List the latest baseline of a component in a UCM stream one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132683/6309)" to get those latest baselines.

The [OP bhardwajme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12966398/bhardwajme) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032476/how-to-rebase-in-clearcase-on-latest-baselines/63036258#comment111707333_63036258):

> it worked: I had written a script to do all the stuff:
>
> - first I got the latest baselines from `cleartool lsbl  -s -comp C -stream S | tail -1` for all the components and moved them into a text file then
> - passed the baseline names to command `cleartool rebase -baseline baseline-selector` command.

Comment: ok thanks @Vonc let me try that, but very strange they do not have a latest baseline option.

Comment: Thanks @VonC yes it worked, I had written a script to do all the stuff, first I  got the latest baselines from `cleartool lsbl  -s -comp C -stream S | tail -1` for all the components and moved them into a text file then passed the baseline names to command `cleartool rebase -baseline baseline-selector` command, off course Syntax could be wrong but it worked, thanks for your help.

Comment: @bhardwajme Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.